# Wordpress theme not letting me edit the text

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I was trying to edit the box text and its not letting me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPba1.png)When i hover over it and click edit these are my options[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2Rnr.png) and option 2 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7h6Fa.png) and option 3[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zO5tE.png)

I have tried to check everything on the options menu but still no luck getting a way to edit the text

Comment: Which theme? Can’t you edit text in Appearance->Widgets?